# How to sum of all values of column( consumption) for example Final reading - initial reading= consumption

Tags: reporting-services

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByisdDc6eMYSTmJ5UE1BSGo2cE0/view?usp=sharing
I want to do sum of all values of consumption column group wise.

Comment: Your question should include all the essential parts, and not only links to external resource.

Answer (score 0):

Just Right Click on Table Row and Insert Row Below with text box value

```
[Sum(consumption)] 
OR
[Sum(Final Reading)] - [Sum(Initial Reading)]
```

If you have Row Grouping on table then Inset Row "Outside Group Below" with same value